# Show InterstitialAd Before opening link in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, startapp

load my ad before performing launchURL.

```
buttonactionL: () async{
                await StartApp.showInterstitialAd();
                String url = "https://google.com";
                _launchURL(url);
              },
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `showAds` method and in the completion of `onAdClosed` and `onAdFailedToLoad` perform `launchURl` operation:

```
  void showAds() {

    _interstitialAd = InterstitialAd(
      adUnitId: AdHelper.interstitialAdUnitId,
      request: AdRequest(),
      listener: AdListener(onAdLoaded: (ad) {
        print("Ad Loaded");
        showAds();
      }, onAdClosed: (ad) {
        print("Closed Ad");
      }, onAdOpened: (ad) {
        print("Opened Ad");
      }, onAdFailedToLoad: (ad, error) {
        print("Failed to load Ad $error");
      }),
    );
    _interstitialAd.load();
  }
```